# C - sorting big binary files with variable length elements

Tags: c, performance, sorting, io, binaryfiles

my problem is the following:

- I have a set of elements with variable length size stored on a binary file that we'll call `data.bin`.
- Each element has a sorting key parameter that we'll call `key`, a size `size` and a file position in data.bin `pos`. These 3 parameters are represented as a structure.

The problem is how to sort `data.bin` effectively.

Right now I have defined a data structure

```
typedef struct {
    int key;
    unsigned int size;
    long int pos;
} index
```

and an array `index indices[]` that contains the values for the elements stored in `data.bin`. This list is successively sorted according to `key` using a quicksort algorithm, which is fast enough even for a very large number of entries (e.g. 10M). Then I use the sorted list `indices` to write the sorted `data.bin` file as `sorted.bin`. The core of my code is the following (here I have intentionally removed error checking parts):

```
size_t mergeBuffIdx = 0;
char  *mergeBuff = (char *) calloc(MERGE_BUFF_SIZE, sizeof(char));

for (unsigned int idx = 0; idx < numEntries; idx++) {
    unsigned int dataSize = indices[idx].size;
    if ((mergeBuffIdx + dataSize) >= MERGE_BUFF_SIZE) {
            fwrite(mergeBuff, sizeof(unsigned char), mergeBuffIdx, sortedDataFile);
            mergeBuffIdx = 0;
    }

    // set the file pointer at the beginning of the data file position
    fseek(dataFile, indices[idx].pos, SEEK_SET);

    // read the data from the file as an unsigned char array
    fread(&mergeBuff[mergeBuffIdx], sizeof(unsigned char), dataSize, dataFile);
    mergeBuffIdx += dataSize;
}

// write remaining data
if (mergeBuffIdx != 0) {
    fwrite(mergeBuff, sizeof(unsigned char), mergeBuffIdx, sortedDataFile);
}
```

This approach, which is quite simple, shortly become very slow when `data.bin` is very large (my general use case is 30GB), the number of entries is around 10M and two successive sorted entries could be very far on the original `data.bin` file. For a `data.bin` file of 1GB this approach can require even more than 30 minutes c.a. even if I'm using an SSD HD.

Do you have some ideas, alternative solutions or approaches to this problem?

I have tried using memory mapped files, with similar or even worst performances. My thought is that the bottleneck is `fseek` call, however, I cannot figure out alternatives and more performant approaches.

Thanks for reading,
S,

Answer (score 0):

With your approach, you only get one element per read, so that's 10 million commands to read the file according to sorted keys. At least the SSD will eliminate the random access overhead.

It should be faster to use an external merge sort to sort the data directly rather than sort keys and make a random access pass. This would allow using read/write for perhaps a bit over 256 MB at a time. The initial pass would read 256MB chunks, sort the elements, then write the 256MB chunks (128 of these would be 32GB). A 16 way merge (2048 reads 16 MB each) followed by a 8 way merge (1024 reads, 32 MB per read) would sort about 32GB of data. For the 16 or 8 way merge, you probably want to use some form of priority queue, such as a heap.

You don't mention if the key/size info is in a separate file. If there's enough spare memory, you could just keep this information in memory during the external merge sort and write it back out when done.